# What is the problem of two each codes that can't maintain the counter value consistency

Tags: operating-system

Here is TAS code

```
boolean TAS(*target) 
{    
    boolean rv = *target;    //Save the initial value
    *target = true;      //Set lock
    return rv;       //Return initial value
}
```

The following codes means two different tries for the increment operation on a thread safe counter using tas to maintain the counter value consistency.

code 1.

```
Counter::Increment() {    
    while (TAS(&lock))       ;    
    value++;    
    lock = FREE;    
    memory_barrier(); 
}
```

code 2.

```
Counter::Increment() {
   while (lock == BUSY && TAS(&lock))       ;    
   value++;    
   lock = FREE;    
   memory_barrier(); 
}
```

What will be the issue of each codes that cannot handle consistency

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `FREE == false` and `BUSY == true`, here is a flow which breaks mutual exclusion:

```
Start thread 1:
    Increment
        TAS
            rv = *lock; // FREE
Switch to thread 2:
    Increment
        TAS
            rv = *lock; // FREE
            *lock = BUSY;
            return rv; // FREE
        Load value 0 from memory and push it into the stack
Switch to thread 1:
            *lock = BUSY;
            return rv; // FREE
        Load value 0 from memory and push it into the stack
        Push 1 into the stack
        Pop two integers from the stack and add them
        Store the result (0 + 1) into value
Switch to thread 2:
        Push 1 into the stack
        Pop two integers from the stack and add them
        Store the result (0 + 1) into value
```